# PHP/MySQLi Error - Will not Insert or Update

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried several variations of the below script and have not come up with a solution that works.  I am basically trying a try/catch to run different MySQLi queries.  When executing I am not getting any errors, but nothing is being Inserted or Update in my DB.

```
$monitor_insert = "INSERT INTO monitors (serial,room,deployed,asset) VALUES ('$monitor','5','$timestamp','$asset')" or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
        if (!mysqli_query($conn, $monitor_insert)) {
            $monitor_update = "UPDATE monitors SET serial = '$monitor', room = '5', deployed = '$timestamp', asset = '$asset')" or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
            if (!mysqli_query($conn, $monitor_update)) {
                echo "<p>Nothing Worked!!!</p>";
            }
            else {
                $audit_update = "INSERT INTO audit (code,info) VALUES ('15',Monitor $monitor has been updated to deployed by $uid')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $audit_update);
            }
        }
        else {
            $audit_update = "INSERT INTO audit (code,info) VALUES ('17',Monitor $monitor has been added by manual scan by $uid')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $audit_update);

            $audit_update = "INSERT INTO audit (code,info) VALUES ('15',Monitor $monitor has been updated to deployed by $uid')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $audit_update);
        }
```

Lines 1-11 are the lines that are not working.

Comment: Add some debugging statements. Check and print the response of _each_ query, so you know which path you are going down. I assume that `mysqli_query()` is returning false, and you are ignoring it.

Comment: Reading your queries, it appears as if you have incorrect quotation, you are missing opening quotes on your string. `('15', 'Monitor $monitor has been updated to deployed by $uid')`

Comment: Thank you @MattClark.  The missing quotes were my down fall.  I guess I just needed a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Working Script:

```
$monitor_insert = "INSERT INTO monitors (serial,room,deployed,asset) VALUES ('$monitor','5','$timestamp','$asset')" or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
        if (!mysqli_query($conn, $monitor_insert)) {
            $monitor_update = "UPDATE monitors SET serial = '$monitor', room = '5', deployed = '$timestamp', asset = '$asset')" or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
            if (!mysqli_query($conn, $monitor_update)) {
                echo "<p>Nothing Worked!!!</p>";
            }
            else {
                $audit_update = "INSERT INTO audit (code,info) VALUES ('15','Monitor $monitor has been updated to deployed by $uid')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $audit_update);
            }
        }
        else {
            $audit_update = "INSERT INTO audit (code,info) VALUES ('17','Monitor $monitor has been added by manual scan by $uid')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $audit_update);

            $audit_update = "INSERT INTO audit (code,info) VALUES ('15','Monitor $monitor has been updated to deployed by $uid')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $audit_update);
        }
```